# Un-subscribe method throwing an undefined method update_attributes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have a newsletter application that I built from the ground up and I'm trying to implement a unsubscribe feature.

However, when users click un-subscribe the logs are showing a un-defined method update_attributes error for NilClass.

What am I doing wrong?

**subscribers_controller.rb**

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController    
  def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)

    if @subscriber.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def unsubscribe
    subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_unsubscribe_hash(params[:unsubscribe_hash])
    if subscriber.update_attributes(:subscription, false)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Error while un-subscribing, please try again"
    end
  end

  private

  def subscriber_params
    params.require(:subscriber).permit(:email, :category_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :category => {},
                                      category_attributes: [:id, :name, :category_type, :created_at, :updated_at])
  end

   def permitted_params
    params.permit(:email, :category_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :category => {},
                                      category_attributes: [:id, :name, :category_type, :created_at, :updated_at])
  end

  def attr_params_category
    params.require(:account).permit(category_attributes: [:id, :name, :category_type, :created_at, :updated_at, :category => {}])
  end

end
```

**subscriber.rb**

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :add_unsubscribe_hash

  belongs_to :category  
  has_many :quote_histories

  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true

  def choose_quote(cat)
    quote = cat.quotes.uniq_quote_for(self.id).order("RANDOM()").first 
    return nil if quote.nil? # so if we didn't able to find in quote lets return from here with nil!k
    return quote if self.quote_histories.create quote ande(quote_id: quote.id) # so here we won't need to test for nil! 
    #so this will reduce the time to perform this operation
  end

  private

  def add_unsubscribe_hash
    self.unsubscribe_hash = SecureRandom.hex
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "subscribers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "unsubscribe_hash"
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  get 'subscribers/unsubscribe/:unsubscribe_hash' => 'subscribers#unsubscribe', :as => 'unsubscribe'
```

**and then in the mail view template:**

```
  <span><%= link_to 'un-subscribe', unsubscribe_url(@subscriber.unsubscribe_hash) %></span>
```

**Debugging logs**

```
2014-11-20T22:17:15.937062+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/subscribers/unsubscribe/cbdb9b40962f1cc6b475096b73c6d5fd" host=motiv8.io request_id=981ed2f0-390e-4d33-888f-26aa8c8060ff fwd="99.234.25.253" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=1754
2014-11-20T22:17:15.927014+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/subscribers/unsubscribe/cbdb9b40962f1cc6b475096b73c6d5fd" for 99.234.25.253 at 2014-11-20 22:17:15 +0000
2014-11-20T22:17:15.932546+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-20T22:17:15.932548+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError ("cbdb9b40962f1cc6b475096b73c6d5fd"):
2014-11-20T22:17:15.932550+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:32:in `unsubscribe'
2014-11-20T22:17:15.932552+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-20T22:17:15.932553+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-20T22:17:15.930282+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SubscribersController#unsubscribe as HTML
2014-11-20T22:17:15.930302+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"unsubscribe_hash"=>"cbdb9b40962f1cc6b475096b73c6d5fd"}
2014-11-20T22:17:15.931362+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
```

**and rails c:**

```
Subscriber.find_by_unsubscribe_hash("cbdb9b40962f1cc6b475096b73c6d5fd")
  Subscriber Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "subscribers".* FROM "subscribers"  WHERE "subscribers"."unsubscribe_hash" = 'cbdb9b40962f1cc6b475096b73c6d5fd' LIMIT 1
  Subscriber Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "subscribers".* FROM "subscribers"  WHERE "subscribers"."unsubscribe_hash" = 'cbdb9b40962f1cc6b475096b73c6d5fd' LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your unsubscribe action.

Replace

```
if subscriber.update_attributes(:subscription, false)
```

with

```
if subscriber.update_attribute(:subscription, false)
```

here `#update_attributes` can take hash like {subscription: false}, but you passed two different arguments. So the similar solution is:

```
if subscriber.update_attributes({subscription: false})
```

Anyways, I updated the whole blocks of unsubscribe action's code a little bit.

```
 def unsubscribe
   subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_unsubscribe_hash(params[:unsubscribe_hash])
   if subscriber and subscriber.update_attribute(:subscription, false)
     redirect_to root_path
   elsif subscriber.nil?
     flash[:notice] = "Subscription not found"
   else
     flash[:notice] = "Error while un-subscribing, please try again"
  end
end
```